# energy norm for transport equation

Tags: pde, stability, hyperbolic-pde

I asked this question before but did not have any luck with an answer. It might be a student level question but I need to understand that with possibly some help. I am considering the hyperbolic equation of the form $$u_t+\frac{x}{T-t}u_x=0$$ and some initial data $u(x,0)=u_0(x)$. I would like to claim that this is a well posed problem in $\mathbb{L}^2$ on $[0,T]$. For that existence, uniqueness and stability needs to be established. So I have the following steps to achieve that.

Step 1: there is a change of variables I can employ as $z=x*(T-t)$. Then for $v(z(t,x),t)=u(x,t)$ I can find $$u_t=v_t+v_z(-x),\; u_x=v_z(T-t).$$Plug them into original equation I obtain an equivalent formulation to the original problem(up to a change of variables): $$v_t=0,\; v(z,0)=u_0(z/T,0).$$ The alternative formulation is clearly trivially has a unique solution for all $t\in [0,T]$, thus I claim the original problem does as well. Moreover, $u(x,T)=v(0,T)=u_0(0,0)$, so even though it initially looks like a not defined p.d.e. at that time it does have a solution.

Step 2: show stability via energy methods. For an arbitrary hyperbolic equation $w_t-a(y)w_y=0, \; y \in [0,1]$:
\begin{align*}
\frac{d||w||^2}{dt}&=(w_t,w)+(w,w_t)=(a(y)w_y,w)+(w,a(y)w_y)\\
&=(a(y)w_y,w)-(w_y,a(y)w)-(w,a_y(y)w)+a(y)ww|^1_0\\
&\leq max_{y\in [0,1]}|a_y(y)|||w||^2+a(y)ww|^1_0
\end{align*}
Thus, the energy estimate boils down to the bound of $a_y$ provided boundary conditions are bounded. I have to estimate the stability of the original equation for $u(x,t)$ and it is not equivalent to the stability of $v(z,t)$. But from the energy estimate above $a_x=\frac{1}{T-t}$ which is not bounded as $t \to T$. Does that imply that is not well posed or energy methods did not work? What are other approaches to prove stability here as I can explicitly find the solution, so it perfectly stable on $[0,T]$? In this case everything is solvable, but I am considering the general case where the trajectories do have this kind of asymptotic behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is certainly not true that just because one way to prove a result doesn't work, the result is actually false. In other words, just because this way doesn't work doesn't mean that the equation isn't stable.

In your case, you can express the solution $u(x,T)$ using the method of characteristics as $u(x,T)=u_0(y)$ with some $y=y(x)$ (you find $y$ by backtracing the characteristic starting at $x,t=T$). Using this, you will immediately get the estimate $$\|u(\cdot,T)\|_{L^p(0,1)} \le \|u_0(\cdot)\|_{L^\infty(0,1)}.$$

If one follows this a bit, one notices that one can rewrite the equation as
$$
  \left( 1 \atop \frac{x}{T-t} \right)
  \cdot 
  \left( \partial_t \atop \partial_x \right)
  u(x,t)
  = 0.
$$
In other words, the characteristics turn horizontal in the $x-t$ diagram as $t\rightarrow T$; following back all characteristics we find that every characteristic ending in $x,T$ in fact started at $0,0$. In other words, we do indeed find that $u(x,T)=u(0,0)$ as you have already noticed. This yields a trivial stability bound.

What you see is that there are often multiple ways of proving a particular statement. That there are additional ways that do not work does not invalidate the result.

Comment: thanks for the answer. In fact, I'd like to have $$\|u(\cdot,T)\|_{L^p(0,1)} \le \|u_0(\cdot)\|_{L^p(0,1)}$$ for $p=2$, for example. If $p=\infty$ the inequality is trivial, but if I try to write two integrals on both sides in ${L}^2(0,1)$ and do change of variables in one of the integrals, than a Jacobian again creates this singularity and I get stuck with a proof. What are the tools to show the relation between two norms in ${L}^2(0,1)$?

Comment: Well, you can't find a way to prove the result because it's not true :-) You have already proved (and the method of characteristics confirmed) that $u(x,T)=u_0(0)$. So think of a sequence of functions $u_0^{(n)}(x)=(1-x)^n$. For all of these, $\|u^{(n)}(\cdot,T)\|_{L^p}=1$ but $\|u_0^{(n)}(\cdot)\|_{L^p}\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. In other words, there isn't even a $C>0$ so that $\|u^{(n)}(\cdot,T)\|_{L^p} \le C \|u_0^{(n)}(\cdot)\|_{L^p}$ for $p<\infty$. Note that this is true here even for continuous initial conditions; it's only going to be worse for discontinuous ones.

Comment: I see your point. However, can I claim that the problem is stable in $L^2(0,1)$ for $t \in [0,T)$ and stable in $L^{\infty}(0,1)$ for $t\in [0,T]$? And second question, when I solve it using methods of characteristics with a quadratic spline interpolation I observe the $O(h^2)$ convergence rate at $t=T$ when I measure discrete $L^2$ norm. But even though the problem is not $L^2$ well posed there this is just a luck I see that norm to be $O(h^2)$? Am I supposed to measure discrete $L^{\infty}$ then?

Comment: I imagine you can prove $L^p$ estimates with a constant that depends on both $p$ and $(t-T)$. As for the convergence rate -- I don't know.

Comment: As a postscript: what do you mean when you say that you solve the equation using the method of characteristics with a quadratic spline interpolation? Convergence rates for hyperbolic equations are notoriously difficult to prove in the general case, and one would need to start with defining what exactly your proposed method does :-)

Comment: Take $p=2$. As derived in the question, one estimates $||u||_{L^2(0,1)}$ via energy methods, i.e.for any $\epsilon>0,a_x(x,t)\leq \frac{1}{T-\epsilon}$, thus the stability in $L^2$ on $[0,T-\epsilon]$ follows (however not sure how BC come into that inequality since no BC at $x=0$?) and as you pointed out I can have the stability estimate in $L^{\infty}$ for $t=T$ Thus, I have $L^{\infty}$ stability on $[0,T]$ but $L^2$ stability on $[0,T-\epsilon]$ for any $\epsilon$. When I do proofs for the numerical methods it is really the same idea, where functions replaced by the grid functions.

Comment: As for the method: I can find the characteristics, and for each grid point at the new level $t_{n+1}$ I can trace backwards to $t_n$ the characteristic going through that point. Since it is unlikely to be a grid point at $t_n$, I interpolate the value via some polynomial on the interval it passes. I use monotone hermite cubic spline and observe the quadratic convergence for both discrete $L^{\infty}$ and $L^2$ norms. Based on the analysis, I can prove $L^2$ error estimate only for $t<T$ but I seem to observe it even for $t\equiv T$, so I wonder if it is just a luck, or there is some limit?

Comment: My gut tells me that you can probably prove it, using in particular that the solution is constant at $t=T$. Your method does a repeated interpolation from one time step to the next, which is a smoothing operation. So you get something for free here, given that your exact solution is as smooth as a function can get.

Comment: If I consider a smooth function like a parabola for initial data, it is easier. However, if the derivative of the initial profile has a jump, for example, all the error estimates of the interpolation fail and I can't guarantee even convergence in $L^{\infty}$, as the error estimates depend on the derivatives and they might blow up. So, even though the problem is well posed, the numerical method doesn't have to be. Do you have any paper or a book in mind that does make these kind of estimates? This is a part of the numerical algorithm I am developing and I need to do all the math behind it...

Comment: No, sorry, I have nothing to offer beyond the standard finite element literature...

Comment: Wolfgang, I still get back to your answer: you say $\|u(\cdot,T)\|_{L^p(0,1)} \le \|u_0(\cdot)\|_{L^\infty(0,1)}$, but then it is a stability bound and since the method of characteristics is a consistent method, does it imply I have a convergence of the method of characteristics in $L^2$? That is, if my local interpolation error is $O(h^3)$ ,then the error $||e(T)||_2=O(h^2)$? And second: what did I loose from not being able to show $||u(\cdot,T)||_2\leq C||u(\cdot,0)||_2$, it looks to me it doesn't affect the error, I would have it in $L^2$, just different stability constant, is that right?

Comment: I must admit that I don't know the proof of the theorem saying "stability + consistency = convergence" well enough to tell whether your statements are true in general norms.

Comment: isn't it called Lax-equivalence theorem? Usually in the books I would see that it is sufficient to show $||u(t,x)||_2\leq C||u_0(x)||_2$ to deduce stability, but the same norm is used, if I have the estimate $||u(x,T)||_2\leq||u_0(x)||_{\infty}$, that looks weaker than the one I would do when I have $L^2$ norm of both sides. Energy methods tell me that the $||\cdot||_2$ can't be bounded by $||u_0||_2$ but can be bounded by $||u_0||_{\infty}$? What is the intuition behind it?

Comment: You misrepresent the Lax theorem. It doesn't talk about stability of the *continuous* equations but you need that the discrete solution is stable!

Comment: yes, but I can replace energy methods with discrete energy methods, so its somewhat equivalent. In fact, since I solve that with method of characteristics, I can use a continuous version for convenience, assume the mesh is so fine.